# reuse of resource in another sql statement

Tags: php, mysql

i am using php with mySql server, pretty new to all the sql and i have a question:
i have a query:

```
$book_copy_user =  "SELECT * FROM copy_book " .
                   "JOIN copy_user_own " .
                   "ON copy_book.copy_id = copy_user_own.copy_id " .
                   "WHERE copy_user_own.user_id=1";

$res1 =mysql_query($sql1) or die (mysql_error());
```

which returns something like

```
[{"copy_id":"1","book_id":"1","user_id":"1"},
{"copy_id":"2","book_id":"2","user_id":"1"},
{"copy_id":"3","book_id":"3","user_id":"1"},
{"copy_id":"4","book_id":"4","user_id":"1"}]
```

i would like to do 3 different select on the result with a where clause, but when trying to so it tells me that there is more the one column.

my question is:
is there a way that i can use the select result and apply select on it?
if so how can i relate to the fields of the in the select result?

please provide code samples

thanks you all you are saints :)

Answer (score 1):

You can select the data into a [temporary table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) and perform more queries on that table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table SELECT ...
```

But I think it would be best if you posted your actual problem, it is very likely that there are much better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM copy_book JOIN copy_user_own ON copy_book.copy_id = copy_user_own.copy_id WHERE copy_user_own.user_id=1) WHERE copy_id = 4
```

althrough I'm not sure if it works in mysql.

No, after running select you cannot apply another on it.